# Converting a pytorch .ckpt file to .bin file

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, file-type, bin, ckpt

I have a pytorch `.ckpt` file and I need to convert this to `.bin` file.

I have tried to execute that code in Python 3.10.11:

```
import torch

# Load the checkpoint file
checkpoint = torch.load("checkpoint.ckpt")

# Extract the model parameters
params = checkpoint["model_state_dict"]

# Save the parameters to a .bin file
torch.save(params, "model.bin")
```

And I got this error:

```
File "D:\Model\trial_ckpt converter.py", line 4, in <module>
    checkpoint = torch.load("checkpoint.ckpt")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 797, in load
    with _open_zipfile_reader(opened_file) as opened_zipfile:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 283, in __init__
    super().__init__(torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(name_or_buffer))
RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory
```

Anyone knows any solution about this?